# Calculate 3-volume in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, integration, volume

If I want to calculate the number of boxes that have proper width, length and height of 1 that I can fit into some region of spacetime (assuming that for the first instant for which I'm trying to calculate the number of boxes they have a velocity of zero to avoid length contraction complications) given some metric,

Would that be the following integral?

$\int \sqrt{g}dx^{3}\tag{1}$

Where $g$ is only the spatial part of the metric tensor and $dx^{3}$ is the wedge product of the differentials of the three spatial coordinates.